# How do I implement Javas Collections.addAll() with a HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer> >?

Tags: java, collections, nested

I was trying to use the build in `Collections.addAll()` method but can not figure out the correct way to do so with the nested data structure. Any direction or documentation on this area would be greatly appreciated.

```
private Map<String, Set<Integer>> index;
index = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();

if (index.containsKey(word) == false)
{
    index.put(word, new HashSet<>());
}

public void addAll(String[] words)
{
    // TODO Fill this in.
    for (String wordIndex : words)
    {
        wordIndex = clean(wordIndex);
        if (!index.containsKey(wordIndex))
        {

        }
    }
    // Collections.addAll(words, index);
    // for (String word : index.keySet())
    // {
    // System.out.printf("%d", word);
    //
    // for (Integer position : index.get(word))
    // {
    // System.out.printf(", %s", position);
    //
    // // add each word/position pair.
    // index.get(word).add(position);
    //
    // }
    // System.out.printf("%n");
    //
    // }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the key or the value is here.   Why does `addAll` take a `String[]` when you're mapping individual strings to `Set<Integer>`? (Though you might take a look at [Guava's `Multimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), if you don't need to roll your own implementation.)

Comment: The keys are the words in 'String[ ] words'. The values at this point would be an empty HashSet of Integers. This Multi-map looks interesting. I will read into it. Thank you for the help @Louis.

Comment: If you just want to put an empty `Set` in for each element...then just loop through the array and call `put` on each element?

Answer (score 0):

**What you are trying to do** :

Based on your code snippet, I have vaguely ascertained that you are trying to add array of strings(String []) to a List of Strings using addAll
method in  Collections Class

**Problem** :

In your code you used  //Collections.addAll(words, index).
The best way to find out if this is valid is to refer to  JAVA SDK API.

I have copied the below snippet from the documentation ;

public static  boolean addAll(Collection c,
                             T... elements)

If you look at the above ;

a) The first parameter of addAll takes any datastructure which extends Collection Interface .(LIST , SET ,..etc)
   In your example this can be  LIST  l = new ArrayList()

b) The second parameter of addALL takes array of values of the type of Collection you are using in a)
   In your example this can be  new String a =  new String[] {"a" , "b" ,"c"}

**Solution**:

In your addAll method do the following ;

List s = new ArrayList()
  Collections.addAll(s , words)